# Need advices on Headless drupal with Angular 4 Front

Tags: angular, drupal

I'm working on a project using Drupal 8 Headless with Angular 4 on front-end.
Things are getting a bit complicated as some URL path will lead to another domain name BUT this new domain name needs to keep the same header as the Angular 4 front-end.

In other words :

I'm on website.com using Drupal on back-end and Angular on Front-end, cool.
I'm going to tool.website.com, which is using Drupal on back-end and Vanilla JS on front-end.

But I have to have the SAME header on both situations, with the same data and design. When users will be on tool.website.com, the header will be generated with vanilla JS. And i'm having a grasp on how to do it the best way. I think that if I include the Angular bundle.js (the entire compiled app) and use it on tool.website.com, it will display the entire app, but I just need the header.

I thought about :

- Creating my app with angular, build and use the bundle.js for website.com, and ONLY build the header component (a new bundle.js) for tool.website.com (is that possible?)
- Creating another angular app only for the header, build it and use the bundle.js for tool.website.com
- Creating the tool.website.com header with good old JS, somehow copying the Angular header existing on website.com

The solution might not be in those 3 situations, basically I just need to have the same header on both website.

Any idea how should I do it?

Thanks alot :)